# In Android, when rotate the image it slowly dissappear.

Tags: android

I used the the below code to rotate the image. There is no problem in image rotation, but when i rotate the image the image pixels was reduced. if i rotate continuously means the image will disappeared. How can i solve this problem.

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:text="Click here to Rotate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ImageResizeTestActivity.java**

```
public class ImageResizeTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button click;
    ImageView img;
    static File rotated_File;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        String fname = "Rotated_Image.jpg";
        rotated_File = new File("/sdcard/" + fname);
        click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!(rotated_File.exists())) {
                    Log.v("Inside if", "if");
                    rotateImage();
                } else {
                    Log.v("Inside else", "else");
                    rotateImage(rotated_File.getAbsolutePath());
                }

            }
        });
    }

    protected void rotateImage(String absolutePath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePath);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(),
                myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        saveImage_Rotate(rotated);
        img.setImageBitmap(rotated);
    }

    protected void rotateImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.test);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(),
                myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        saveImage_Rotate(rotated);
        img.setImageBitmap(rotated);
    }

    static void saveImage_Rotate(Bitmap dest2) {

        if (rotated_File.exists())
            rotated_File.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(rotated_File);
            dest2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Initially my Image is]  after rotating [image: Rotated image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look on the problem. You save the jpg several times, and during the (lossy)compression it will degrade more and more.

I'd suggest you use png instead

Comment: It works, but it take more time to rotate. more than 20 seconds

Comment: I guess it is because it is a larger file. You could try webp-format, but think it is destructive as well. 

Is it neccesary to rotate several times? if you want to rotate 90 degrees 2-3 times, it might be better to do it in one step of 180 or 270 degrees instead. (If you would rotate more than that, then you might consider not saving the actual file until you have a rotation that you are satisfied with, then apply that to the original file)